# How loaders survive configuration changes?

Tags: android, loader

https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832
The article mentioned above states that

> Loaders survive Configuration changes.

So the data I just retrieved will be available after device rotation.

It also tells that

> Loaders don't stay around forever

They will be automatically cleaned up when requesting Activity or Fragment is destroyed. So if an Activity is destroyed when a device rotates which implies loaders being cleaned up how can I retrieve data from Loader?

Comment: cannot you use `ViewModel`s?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of LoaderManagerImpl uses the **ViewModel** internally. The ViewModel class is designed to hold and manage UI-related data in a life-cycle conscious way. This allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

Therefore, you can retrive data from Loader when your activity is recreated. If your activity is permanently destroyed when you click the Back button, the Loader is destroyed with it.

Comment: Don't you think the activity is destroyed during screen rotations?

Comment: @AravindPulagam but [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) is not

Comment: @AravindPulagam The activity is destroyed, and then the system immediately calls onCreate() to recreate when the screen rotates. It doesn't mean that the activity is permanently destroyed. The ViewModel can survive so long as the activity isn't permanently destroyed.